# Calculate edges in complete graph with SQL

Tags: sql, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, impala

Suppose we have a table *T* that represents the edges of an (undirected) graph. There are two columns *X* and *Y* where the entry in column *X* is the starting node and the entry in *Y* is the ending node.

For example, the following graph:

[image]

Could be represented by the following table:

```
|-----|----|
|  X  |  Y |
|-----|----|
|  a  |  e |
|  b  |  c |
|  d  |  c |
|-----|----|
```

Can a SQL query be used to generate a table that contains all the edges of all the disjoint complete graphs implied by *T*? That is, the graph generated from *T* by connecting any two nodes with an edge if there exists some path (of any length!) between them.

For the example above, the completed graph would look like:

[image]

And the table could be:

```
|-----|----|
|  X  |  Y |
|-----|----|
|  a  |  e |
|  b  |  c |
|  d  |  c |
|  b  |  d |
|-----|----|
```

In general, I get the impression that this **cannot** be done with a SQL query without using some kind of recursive common table expression. Using a loop, the problem could be solved by joining *T* to itself to generate a list of nodes connected by a path of length 2, and then joining it again for paths of length 3 etc., stopping after *n* steps where *n* is the number of nodes.

However, I don't think such loops are possible in "standard" SQL. Is there an idiomatic SQL method of doing this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  This requires recursive CTEs and not all databases support them.

Comment: Does it require recursive CTEs? My hope was that it wouldn't necessarily.

Comment: @Mrfence I have no proof but I'd be happy to bet money that this is not possible in straight SQL-92.  So yes, this probably requires recursive CTEs.

Comment: Indeed, I fear this is the case. Do you know of a reference that describes exactly which classes of problems cannot be solved in SQL? Or in other words, what exactly is it about this problem that means it cannot be done?